# angular search option autocomplete multiple fields

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular project and i want to have a form with a search option and the fields with default data from my api. When i select one option from search i want to update other fields with the new values.
Let say my option list looks like this
`[{name:'user1', home:'home1', gender:'gender1'}, {name:'user2', home:'home2', gender:'gender2'}, ....]`

When the user enter the page the fields are completed with data from first index of the option list then the search option is made by the name and when the user enters *user2* the other fields get their matching value from my option list.

Any suggestions on how can i do this? I tried this solution https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples but is only for one field.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz design of what you want to achive. ? (for example one search with two input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a subscription to the option field:

```
   this.myForm.controls['yourOptionFieldName'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      setValue();
    });
```

... when the option field change set the new object to the rective form

```
setValue(){
   this.myForm.setValue({
       name:'user2',
       home:'home2',
       gender:'gender2'
    })
}
```

Don't forget destroy the subscription..

I suggest that is even better if you create an endpont that retrive user data. Is a bad idea manipulate such object in your web application, you could take care the system resources...
When search change retrive the user data, then populate the form.